# Dealing with OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, for-loop, out-of-memory

Is there a proper way to deal with Out Of Memory Exceptions while looping through a large list and adding objects from that list? What is the proper way to go about doing this? I have a large Linq query that returns around 600K items. I then go through each item and add it to an object. The code is below.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GrabData();
    }

    public static void GrabData()
    {
        decimal? TotalNetClaim = 0;
        using (var Context = new VSCMeSnapEntities())
        {              
            List<DriveTimeObject> DataFile = new List<DriveTimeObject>(); 
            DriveTimeObject DT = new DriveTimeObject();
            DateTime ParamDate = new DateTime(2015, 05, 30);
            List<viewDriveTimeFileDump> DataQuery = new List<viewDriveTimeFileDump>();

            DataQuery = (from z in Context.viewDriveTimeFileDumps select z).ToList();

            foreach (var item in DataQuery)
            {
                decimal? AmountChargedParts = DT.GetAmountChargedParts(item.chrComponSts.Trim(), item.mnsTotalParts);
                decimal? AmountChargedPartsTax = DT.GetAmountChargedPartsTax(item.chrComponSts.Trim(), item.mnsTotalPartTax);
                decimal? AmountChargedLabor = DT.GetAmountChargedLabor(item.chrComponSts.Trim(), item.mnsTotalLabor);
                decimal? AmountChargedLaborTax = DT.GetAmountChargedLaborTax(item.chrComponSts.Trim(), item.mnsTotalLaborTax);
                int? DaysOut = DT.GetDaysOutClaim(item.intRepairFacilCode, item.dtmContPurchDate, item.dtmReported);
                long? MilesOut = DT.GetMilesOutClaim(item.intRepairFacilCode, item.inbIncurMiles, item.inbOrigMiles);
                decimal? deductible = DT.GetDeductible(item.chrContSts, item.mnsDeduct);
                decimal? netClaim = DT.GetNetClaim(item.chrComponSts.Trim(), item.mnsTotalParts, item.mnsTotalPartTax, item.mnsTotalLabor, item.mnsTotalLaborTax, item.mnsDeduct);

                DataFile.Add(new DriveTimeObject
                {
                    DealerNumber = item.chrDlrNum,
                    VSCName = item.chvVSCName,
                    IcLocationNumber = item.IcLocationNumber,
                    IcRegion = item.IcRegion,
                    Identifier = item.chrIdentifier,
                    ContractNumber = item.chrContNum,
                    VIN = item.chrVIN,
                    CoverageCode = item.CvgCode,
                    ClaimNum = item.intClaimNum,
                    OriginalMiles = item.inbOrigMiles,
                    ContractPurchaseDate = item.dtmContPurchDate,
                    IncurMiles = item.inbIncurMiles,
                    DateReported = item.dtmReported,
                    DaysOutClaim = DaysOut,
                    MilesOut = MilesOut,
                    RepairFacilityNumber = item.intRepairFacilCode,
                    FacilityName = item.chvFacilityName,
                    ZipFive = item.chrZipFive,
                    FacilityAdvisor = item.chrFacilAdvisor,
                    ComponentStatus = item.chrComponSts,
                    ComponentStatusWord = item.ComponDesc,
                    ComponentCode = item.chrComponCode,
                    StatusMasterDescription = item.MasterDesc,
                    ComponentDescription = item.chvComponDesc,
                    Parts = AmountChargedParts,
                    PartsTax = AmountChargedPartsTax,
                    Labor = AmountChargedLabor,
                    LaborTax = AmountChargedLaborTax,
                    Deductible = deductible,
                    NetClaim = netClaim,
                    CarrierCode = item.intCarrierCode,
                    NetworkStatus = item.NetworkStatus,
                    AddOn = item.chrAddOn,
                    ETCDate = item.ETC,
                    ATCDate = item.ATC,
                    LaborTime = item.reaLaborTime,
                    PaidDate = item.dtmPdDate,
                    PaymentID = item.intPaymentID,
                    BatchNumber = item.intBatchNum

                });

                TotalNetClaim += netClaim;
            }
            Context.Dispose();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(TotalNetClaim);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

I run out of memory during the `foreach` loop and I was wondering how I should go about adjusting my code to make this work.

Comment: What is the point of the `DataFile` List? You keep lots of objects in it but never use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to prevent out of memory is to not run out of memory.  Which means you need to get rid of objects you don't need.

Without learning more of your use case, it is hard to suggest the fix.  Regardless of that, it's bad practice to have so many objects in memory that you run out and crash.  **Only keep in memory what you need.**

One fix is to not use RAM memory, and instead use hard drive memory.  Ex: You can write those objects to a database and get rid of them, so you don't keep them around.  Considering you have 600k objects, you could do these in batches of 10k/25k records. Then when you need the objects, you can query them.  If you need to do calculations with all the objects, I would recommend doing those operations using SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `DriveTimeObject` and storing it in a `List<DriveTimeObject>` called `DataFile`. Assuming there are 600k items in your `DataQuery`, this means that your list also contains 600k items.

However, you are not using that list at all so it's just chewing up all of your memory for no reason. Remove that and save yourself a whole tonne of memory and it should also run a lot faster.